# Android MVP optimization

Tags: android, design-patterns, mvp

I have just started using MVP in android development. As per different tutorials found on web, I am creating 5(viewInterface, presenterInterface, presenterImpl, interector, and interectorImpl) files for each fragment. Is there any way by which i can reduce the number of these files.

Thanks

Comment: Before you start using examples from the web, you should think about your app software design. Are you sure that you need these "5 files"?! Take paper and a pen, make some diagrams or whatever. What Im trying to say, is that before you take and use stuff from web, you should know for which stuff exactly to look and which part of that to take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have come to know basics of Clean Architechure. The following example depicts how actual your MVP pattern is implemented.

Example:

```
interface BaseContract {
        interface BaseView {
            //Methods for View
            void onDoSomething();
        }

        interface BasePresenter {
            void doSomething();

        }
    }

    class BaseMainPresenter implements BaseContract.BasePresenter {
        BaseContract.BaseView view;

        BaseMainPresenter(BaseContract.BaseView view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        @Override
        public void doSomething() {
            if (view != null)
                view.onDoSomething();
        }
    }

    class DemoClass implements BaseContract.BaseView {

        //Create object of Presenter 

        /****
         * Example :
         * BaseMainPresenter baseMainPresenter = new BaseMainPresenter(this);
         */
        @Override
        public void onDoSomething() {
            //Deal with Context here.
        }
    }
```

You can refer as MVP Pattern with this following link :-

- Link : https://github.com/Archish27/Retrozing

Answer (score 0):

Yeah-  don't do whatever it is you're doing.  MVP is a good pattern for some usecases, but there's never a reason for more than 3 classes-  a model, a view, and a presenter.  Any tutorial that is going into that depth is being way over formal and is actually a harmful tutorial.

Android is basically MVP by default.  Your Presenter is your Activity class.  Your View is your layout-  that hierarchy of View classes.  Your model is whatever data you need to run your app.

Don't get hung up on overly formal explanations of patterns, and don't apply patterns to apply a pattern.  The real use of patterns isn't a goal to make your application look like that, the real use of a pattern is a way to describe what you're doing to other architects/programmers.  You should never look at a pattern and try to find ways to use it or look at a problem and think "what patterns can I use".  You should see a problem, think of a solution, and that may be a pattern.  By the time you're ready to study patterns, you should have seen the vast majority of them in code already.

Comment: I wouldn't say that Android is MVP: it's more like MP+V where M and P are bound extremely tight. A clean MVP Presenter can easily be a platform-independent mediator.